# How to debug crashed android native library?

Tags: android, debugging, native

I am runing junit test for native library(C++), native library process crashed and logcat shows:

```
I/ActivityManager(  161): Force stopping package xxxxx uid=10043
I/ActivityManager(  161): Start proc xxxxx for added application xxxx: pid=1656 uid=10043 gids={1015}
I/TestRunner( 1656): started: testAddressBook(xxxxx.AddressBookTest)
F//system/bin/app_process( 1656): stack corruption detected: aborted
I/ActivityManager(  161): Process xxxxx (pid 1656) has died.
```

Where xxxxx is the process name.

I try to follow instruction on http://source.android.com/porting/debugging_native.html , but the instruction is confusing:

*If it crashes, connect with aproto and run logcat on the device*

What is aproto? I can't find it. Nor "stack" tool.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

-Henry

Comment: it seems that 'aproto' is replaced by 'adb' now.

Answer (score 5):

```
F//system/bin/app_process( 1656): stack corruption detected: aborted
```

That sounds like you're trashing a local variable. Here's a really popular way to do that:

```
char localVar[16];
sprintf(localVar, "And this is why sprintf is the devil");
```

That's not exactly what you asked for, but I hope it helps anyway.